# how to create a code that show all the data in my databse with specific time?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

Is it possible to create a conditional operator with two strings?
Here are my code:

```
String expired_data="02/11/2016";
If(datetoday<=expired_data){
      //All the data that expired today will show
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use actual `Date`s then you can use [`.before()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before-java.util.Date-) or [`.after()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after-java.util.Date-) or [`.compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo-java.util.Date-) to compare the dates.

An example using `.before()`

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date expiryDate = format.parse("2016-11-02");
    Date today = new Date();
    if (expiryDate.before(today)) {
        // then logic
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // couldn't parse date strings
}
```

Possibly better (depending on your use) to use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) rather than [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

Furthermore as an example of using this, say you have some `Data` objects that are have an associated expiry date,

```
public class Data {

    // getters/setters omitted for brevity
    public LocalDateTime expiryDate;
    public String value;

    public Data(LocalDateTime expiry, String value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.expiryDate = expiry;
    }

    public boolean isExpired() {
        return expiryDate.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

and you are interested in doing something with the expired data...

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    // Setup
    LocalDateTime nextWeek = LocalDateTime.now().plusWeeks(1);
    LocalDateTime lastWeek = LocalDateTime.now().minusWeeks(1);
    List<Data> allData = new ArrayList<Data>() {{
        add(new Data(lastWeek, "Hello"));
        add(new Data(nextWeek, "I'm NOT expired"));
        add(new Data(lastWeek, "World"));
    }};

    // Print values of expired data
    allData.stream()
        .filter(Data::isExpired)
        .forEach(data -> System.out.print(data.value));

}
```

Outputs `HelloWorld`.

**What Happened**

We created a list of `Data` and added three instances to that list, two of which had an expiry date of last week, and one with an expiry next week. Using the [java.util.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) API and the comparison operations provided by [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) we filtered the list to only those that were expired, then output the value of those objects.